# Can I install my own software on a Nook Color?

Tags: android, nook

I'm wondering about buying a Nook Color, but I don't want it unless I can write and install my own apps for it.  I don't qualify for the Nook Color development program; I just want to noodle around.  Do I have to root it and install another version of Android first?

Comment: My understanding is that you can root the Nooks and put stock Android on them, so yes.

Comment: Okay, I'm missing something.  In what way is "Can I develop on this platform" not related to software development?

Comment: SO is generally for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the stock Color Nook does not allow you to enable loading APKs from "Unknown Sources", however, there's [an article here](http://myraroldan.com/wp/2011/05/nook-color-to-android-table-without-rooting/) that shows you how to make a bootable SD card to enable loading apps without rooting.

I have sent my own APKs to a friend who has a rooted color nook, which work fine (I've even got an emulator with the same resolution as his nook to preview what they look like on his device before I send them to him).